# database configuration for siremis ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'siremis'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database, kamailio

ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'siremis'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
I amgetting this error during the SIREMIS Setup in the browser. Any ideas on hoiw to resolve this ? I am wasting all my time on this since a week.

Comment: why dont you try to grant siremis user for related database.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

Likely you missed the installation step for granting access for **siremis** user to MySQL server:

- https://kb.asipto.com/siremis:install51x:main#database_configuration

Answer (score 0):

enter this in mysql command line via root user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON siremis.* TO siremis@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'siremisrw';
```